# ASP.NET web application - having problems with my database connectivity since switching fro mysql to access db

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, ms-access

I have created an ASP.NET web app for a university project and I had it all working as intended with full functionality using local mysql db. Due to reasons out of my control, I have been instructed to change the database to an access one. So I have done this, changed out the 'sql' statements for 'Oledb' ones and one half of my app works fine with the new changes, but I am having issues with the other half. I will add my connection string from my web.config page, followed by the issues i'm having. Can someone see where i'm going wrong?

```
  <add name="newregDBConnectionString"  connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Database1.accdb"
  providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

I have two issues, the first is that I have a registration page, you fill out a form and the details are stored in the database. When I click submit to send the details to the DB, I get an error;

[image: RegIssue]

The second issue is that I have a gridview, which using a datasource, displays the people registered, but when I click the view button, I get the following error;

[image: ViewIssue]

I added

> "throw new
>   Exception(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);"
>   to my global.aspx page to see the error and it showed the following;

[image: Exception]

It makes it seem as though my connection string is incorrect in my web.config page but the other half of my app is working with database connectivity (my login page), so I can't see the problem. Apologies for the long post, I would greatly appreciate someone pointing out where i'm being stupid! Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        {                                           
            if (parentRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || surnameBox.Text == "" || postcodeBox.Text == "" || teleBox.Text == "" || emailBox.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                    successLabel.Text = ("");
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }                 
                else
                {
                    OleDbCommand pa = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO parent(parentID, firstname, surname, postcode, telephone, email, password) VALUES (@parentID, @firstname, @surname, @postcode, @telephone, @email, @password)", connect);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parentID", userBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcodeBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", teleBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailBox.Text);
                    pa.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                    connect.Open();
                    pa.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();
                }

                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    surnameBox.Text = "";
                    postcodeBox.Text = "";
                    teleBox.Text = "";
                    emailBox.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }

            }           
            else if (childRadBtn.Checked)
            {
                if (firstNameBox.Text == "" || dayDobList.Text == "" || monthDobList.Text == "" || yearDobList.Text == "" || genderList.Text == "" || userBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Text == "")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Please ensure all fields have an entry');</script>");
                    successLabel.Text = ("");
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    dayDobList.Text = "";
                    monthDobList.Text = "";
                    yearDobList.Text = "";
                    genderList.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }                 
                else
                {
                    OleDbParameter dob = new OleDbParameter("@dob", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    dob.Value = new DateTime(Int32.Parse(yearDobList.Text), Int32.Parse(monthDobList.Text), Int32.Parse(dayDobList.Text));                      

                    OleDbCommand ca = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO children(childID, firstname, dob, gender, password) VALUES (@childID, @firstname, @dob, @gender, @password)", connect);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@childID", userBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstNameBox.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.Add(dob);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", genderList.Text);
                    ca.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordBox.Text);

                    connect.Open();
                    ca.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                if (IsPostBack)
                {
                    userBox.Text = "";
                    firstNameBox.Text = "";
                    dayDobList.Text = "";
                    monthDobList.Text = "";
                    yearDobList.Text = "";
                    genderList.Text = "";
                    passwordBox.Text = "";
                }              
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's the SQL standard, and then there's actual live databases. Pretty much every DB engine has it's own SQL dialect that is more or less compliant with the standard. Neither MySql nor Access are particularly good here. I no longer consider MySql to even be a modern DB engine (it's fallen way behind over the last decade) and Access, being an in-process engine, is a wholly inappropriate choice for a web site. But assignments are assignments, and often have artificial constraints for practical reasons. The upshot is you'll need to look at every SQL statement to make sure it works with Access.

Comment: And BTW, thanks for making us re-type your code instead of copy/pasting from your question. We really appreciate that. I mean it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah I had it working fine with MySQL but like I said, our professors want us to switch to access. I guess you're being sarcastic in your follow up comment and I always paste my code but figured it isn't chunks of code that need to be viewed, it can all be seen in the screenshots but after reading what you said I have just realised that it's more for people using the code to test things themselves, I never thought of it like that. I am sorry and I will definitely be more considerate when posting in the future.

Comment: No worries, I got it done :) But often this is a good way to have a question sit unanswered, because rather than spending time re-typing people will often just move on to the next question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah it makes so much sense, it definitely wasn't me being lazy I had just never thought about it being for anything other than viewing. Thanks for the heads up, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection("newregDBConnectionString");
```

Notice that `newregDBConnectionString` is in quotes there? It looks like that's the name of a variable holding your connection string. By putting it in quotes, you're passing the text "`newregDBConnectionString`" as the connection string itself, instead of whatever string is inside that variable.

You need to get this connection string value from the configuration manager like you do in the second and third images.

Additionally, in the second image, you have this:

```
SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();
```

This needs to be changed to `OleDbDataSource`.

Comment: Hi again :) So I changed the string to match the second and third pictures, I have updated my original post with the latest error screenshot, along with my pasted code from that class :)

Comment: It won't let me add the image, but the error is; 'An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.' and it is pointing at the 'ca.ExecuteNonQuery();' line (176)

Comment: That's where you need to change sql that was written using MySql's dialect to use Access'.

Comment: I have changed everything that was SQL into OleDb equivalents. Do you mean the 'ExecuteNonQuery' line as I just google and apparently that is a valid OleDb command? Sorry if i'm coming across stupid this is my first time using asp.net and access!

Comment: Oops, I think I see what you mean, @JoelCoehoorn. The line; 'OleDbParameter dob = new OleDbParameter("@dob", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);'. But I can't find an access equivalent for System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime. I have tried a few ideas from other posts online but nothing has worked as of yet, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

your login page has this

```
  OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

while your registration form page is I think you're just passing a string

make it the same as your login page